# Correct configuration for Windows' default console window to fix limited default scroll-back

Tags: json, git, non-ascii-characters, windows-terminal, mintty

am installing Git and I have to choose which terminal emulator to use with my Git bash. I have to choose between Windows' default console window instead of MinTTY(the default terminal of MSYNC) but I prefer the former which has to be configured to use a Unicode font in order to display non-ASCII characters correctly.

I have the latest version of Windows 10 installed and I am using the latest Windows terminal. I have tried to access the settings by 2 ways;

1. Clicking the settings tab opens settings.json file in Microsoft Visual Studio.
2. Pressing and holding tab while clicking the settings tab opens defaults.json (Windows terminal's current default settings). Inside the json file, I found Scrollback settings as below:

```
// Scrollback
        { "command": "scrollDown", "keys": "ctrl+shift+down" },
        { "command": "scrollDownPage", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pgdn" },
        { "command": "scrollUp", "keys": "ctrl+shift+up" },
        { "command": "scrollUpPage", "keys": "ctrl+shift+pgup" },
```

It is from here that I failed to know how to proceed. Here is the full-path to the json file: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\defaults.json

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a lot of confusing information in your question.  Are you asking how to change the scrollback history in Windows Terminal?  How to use Git Bash with Windows Terminal?  How to change the font?  You mention having to choose between the "Windows' default console" and MinTTY, but then you go on to say that you're using Windows Terminal instead of either of those.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hello, I am using Windows terminal as the Windows default console. What I am trying to accomplish is to configure Windows terminal to be able to use a Unicode font in order to display non-ASCII characters correctly.

Comment: Which font do you want to use?  Do you have it installed in Windows already?

Comment: Actually i do not need a specific font, I simply want some characters like in the query below to display correctly in the Windows command prompt, some characters are not displaying well.  
( REG query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont" )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most of the fonts that come with Windows are "Unicode" fonts.  If you are looking for some special glyphs in particular, you may want something like a [Nerd Font](https://www.nerdfonts.com).  To set the font in Windows Terminal, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#text-settings).

Specifically, set the font either in the `"defaults"` section or in the specific profile you are using with Git Bash.  `fontFace` will be the main setting.  My settings.json "defaults" looks like this:

```
   "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
            //"useAcrylic": true, 
            //"acrylicOpacity": 0.75

            // From Nerd Fonts
            // https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
            "fontFace": "CaskaydiaCove NF",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "cursorShape": "filledBox"
        },
```